# Why ResidueSum returns 2 different values?

Tags: functions, complex

I want to calculate the sum of the residues of the function

$$ \frac{\sin(\theta)\tanh(\alpha x)}{-\cos(2xL)+\cos(\theta)}, $$ for $|x| \leq1$. The function has singularities at the points $x_n^\pm = \pm \theta/2L + n \pi/L$ ; the corresponding residues are

$$ \frac{\pm\tanh(\alpha x_n^\pm)}{2L}. $$

I wanted to try out the ResidueSum function, which should sum the residues of a function over a certain interval. When I use

```
ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*a]*Sin[T]/(-Cos[2*x*L] + Cos[T]), (x >= -1 && x <= 1)}, x]
```

it returns the value $1/L$. But when I use

```
ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*a]*Sin[T]/(-Cos[2*x*L] + Cos[T]), Abs[x] <= 1}, x]
```

it returns the value $T/\pi L = \theta / \pi L$.
I'd like to understand why I get 2 different results.

**EDIT :**

For parameter $T=\pi/3$, $a=1000$, $L=10$, I used the following code

```
N[ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*1000]* Sin[Pi/3]/(-Cos[2*x*10] + Cos[Pi/3]), (x >= -1 && x <= 1)}, x]]
```

```
N[ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*1000]* Sin[Pi/3]/(-Cos[2*x*10] + Cos[Pi/3]), Abs[x]<=1}, x]]
```

and got $0.1$ and $0.0333$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Which version are you using, and what is the complete code? If I use any of the two examples you provided in v13.3, I get an error message _ResidueSum::ncsol: Unable to find the sum of residues ..._ and no result.

Comment: @Domen I am on version 13.3.  To obtain a result you have to chose a value for $T$, $L$ and $a$. 
For example, for $T=\pi/3$, $L=10$, $a=1000$, the first function gives me $0.1$, and the second $0.033333$.
Complete code :

N[ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*1000]*
    Sin[Pi/3]/(-Cos[2*x*10] + Cos[Pi/3]), (x >= -1 && x <= 1)}, x]]
N[ResidueSum[{Tanh[x*1000]*
    Sin[Pi/3]/(-Cos[2*x*10] + Cos[Pi/3]), (Abs[x] <= 1)}, x]]

Comment: `(x >= -1 && x <= 1)` and `Abs[x]<=1` are not the same. The first allows only real `x` the second allows complex `x`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Indeed, but here the singularities are all on the real axis, so this shouldn't matter.

Comment: But when `L` or `T` are complex then there are residues also for complex `x`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Mea culpa, I forgot the singularities of the tanh function on the imaginary axis. Of course the difference between the results found with the functions corresponds to the sum of the residues of the tanh. So no bug here.